# Mock test Case for void method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to write test case for start method which calling different methods.
i try this code but it gives me NullPointerException on spyGit.start(mockUserDetails.getUserInput());
Thanks in Advance.

```
public void start(String jiraNumber) throws Exception {
        InputData.loader();
        GitHubJiraIntegrator gitHubJiraIntegrator = new GitHubJiraIntegrator();
        UserDetails userDetailForGit = new UserDetails(InputData.getPropertyByKey("username"), InputData.getPropertyByKey("password"), InputData.getPropertyByKey("gitRepo"));
        UserDetails userDetailForJira = new UserDetails(InputData.getPropertyByKey("username"), InputData.getPropertyByKey("password"), jiraNumber, "Jira");
        if (!jiraNumber.equals("Invalid")) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = gitHubJiraIntegrator.getConnection(userDetailForJira);
            String status = jiraServices.checkJiraStatus(connection);
            String shaOfMaster = gitHubJiraIntegrator.checkJiraProgressStatus(status, jiraNumber);
            if (!shaOfMaster.equals("not needed") && !shaOfMaster.equals("Not In Progress"))
                gitHubServices.createGitHubBranch(userDetailForGit, jiraNumber, shaOfMaster);
        }
```

```
public void test() throws Exception {
        UserDetails mockUserDetails = mock(UserDetails.class);
        HttpURLConnection mockHttp = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        GitHubJiraIntegrator gitHubJiraInt = mock(GitHubJiraIntegrator.class);
        JiraServices mockJiraService = mock(JiraServices.class);
        GitHubJiraIntegrator spyGit = spy(GitHubJiraIntegrator.class);
        GitHubServices mockGitHubServices = mock(GitHubServices.class);
        String jiraNumber = "abc";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(jiraNumber.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        mockUserDetails.setUserInput(jiraNumber);
        System.out.println(mockUserDetails.getUserInput());
        doReturn(mockHttp).when(spyGit).getConnection(mockUserDetails);
        doReturn("In Progress").when(mockJiraService).checkJiraStatus(mockHttp);
        doReturn("1234567890").when(gitHubJiraInt).checkJiraProgressStatus("In Progress", "123");
        String shaKey = spyGit.checkJiraProgressStatus("In Progress", "1234");
        doReturn(201).when(mockGitHubServices).createGitHubBranch(any(), eq("123"), eq(shaKey));
        doNothing().when(spyGit).start(anyString());
        spyGit.start(mockUserDetails.getUserInput());
        verify(spyGit, times(1)).start(anyString());
    }
```

Comment: those are local variables, you can't mock local variables. Also, be more specific in what causes the exception, the method call? the parameter? what?

Comment: cause of exception is mockUserDetails.getUserInput() get null.

Comment: You're using mockito wrong, but either way, you can't mock the variables in your actual code like this

Comment: @Stultuske in start method ``` if (!jiraNumber.equals("Invalid")) ``` jiraNumber getting null value.

Comment: You need to restructure your code to support dependency injection, currently the code is far from clean and therefore not testable. The `GitHubJiraIntegrator` needs to be injected, similar to the `InputData`

Comment: what is the right way to mock variables please help me I am new in mocking.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if that is the exact reason of the exception, but it is worth notice. Before you use cal some mock's method that is returning the data object you should add some definition what it should return.

So instead of

```
UserDetails mockUserDetails = mock(UserDetails.class);
...
System.out.println(mockUserDetails.getUserInput());
```

you should rather write

```
UserDetails mockUserDetails = mock(UserDetails.class);
when(mockUserDetails.getUserInput()).thenReturn(someObjectThatShouldByTheMethod);
System.out.println(mockUserDetails.getUserInput());
```

Comment: now it's not throwing an exception but it does not give me code coverage.